# how to use generic jsonFile handler using guice?

Tags: java, generics, interface, dependency-injection, guice

I have 2 repositories classes:

```
public class ResponseRepository implements IRoutingResponseRepository {

    private final String baselineFileName;

    @Inject
    @Singleton
    public ResponseRepository(@Named("baseline_file") String baselineFileName) {
        this.baselineFileName = baselineFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public E2EResult getBaseLine() {
        E2EResult e2EResult = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try
        {
            e2EResult =  mapper.readValue(new File(baselineFileName), E2EResult.class);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return e2EResult;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StatsRepository implements IRoutingResponseRepository {

    private final String baselineFileName;

    @Inject
    @Singleton
    public StatsRepository(@Named("stats_file") String baselineFileName) {
        this.baselineFileName = baselineFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public StatsObj getStats() {
        StatsObj statsObj = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try
        {
            statsObj =  mapper.readValue(new File(baselineFileName), StatsObj.class);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return statsObj;
    }
}
```

how can I refactor the common code to be generic one?

and also I want guice to use `fileName = E2EResult.csv` when `<E2EResult>` and `fileName = StatsObj.csv` when `<StatsObj>`

I have tried:

but I wrote the generics incorrectly. It shows an error.
And also i'm not sure how to let guice inject different fileName

```
public interface IFileHandler<T> {

    T getContent();
}
```

and

```
public class JsonFileHandler implements IFileHandler<T> {


    String fileName;

    @Inject
    public JsonFileHandler(String file) {
        this.fileName = file;

        //Constants.RESULTS_BASELINE_FILE
    }

    public <T> T getContent() {
        T t = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            t = mapper.readValue(new File(fileName), T.class);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the type variable part, it would be, with this interface:

```
public interface IFileHandler<T> {
    T getContent();
}
```

this implementing class declaration and method signature:

```
class JsonFileHandler<T> implements IFileHandler<T> {
    public T getContent() {
        T t = null;
        // ...
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: but this won't compile: `t = mapper.readValue(new File(fileName), T.class);` for `T.class`

Comment: @EladBenda I see; there is no way to do that (infer the class type from generic type). You'll have to pass it in your implemented method like `getContent(Class<T> type)`

Comment: @GUIDO this is not correct, you can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private final Class<T> cls = (Class<T>) new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {}.getRawType();` to your implementation and get what you need.